# Bitnami-wampstack-7.1.18 installation error

Tags: wamp, bitnami

I am trying to install wamp with bitnami-wampstack-7.1.18-1-windows-x64-installer.exe but were un-successful after multiple tries. 
    I noticed some errors were reported in the BitRock-installer.log file as follow:

> Script output:
>
> Script stderr:   Executing D:/Apps/wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php -v
>   Script exit code: unknown signal
>
> Script output:   Script stderr:  child killed: unknown signal
>
> Error running D:/Apps/wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php -v: child killed:
>   unknown signal
>
> ...
>
> [20:25:58] [mysql:post-installation] End: Installing and Initializing
>   MySQL Database Executing D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/PEAR/.channels" "@@BITROCK_PHP_ROOT@@"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php" Script exit code: unknown signal
>
> Script output:
>
> Script stderr:  child killed: unknown signal
>
> Error running D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/PEAR/.channels" "@@BITROCK_PHP_ROOT@@"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php": child killed: unknown signal
>   Executing D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/PEAR/.channels"
>   "@@BITROCK_APACHE_ROOTDIR@@" "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2"
>   Script exit code: unknown signal
>
> Script output:
>
> Script stderr:  child killed: unknown signal
>
> Error running D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/PEAR/.channels"
>   "@@BITROCK_APACHE_ROOTDIR@@" "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2":
>   child killed: unknown signal Executing
>   D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/PEAR/.registry" "@@BITROCK_PHP_ROOT@@"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php" Script exit code: unknown signal
>
> ... Error running D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\bin/openssl.exe
>   req -config "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\conf\openssl.cnf" -new
>   -keyout "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2/conf/privkey.pem" -passout pass:**** -subj "/O=Bitnami/OU=Certificate generated at installation
>   time/CN=www.example.com" -out
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2/conf/server.csr": child killed:
>   unknown signal Problem running post-install step. Installation may not
>   complete correctly  Error running
>   D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\bin/openssl.exe req -config
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\conf\openssl.cnf" -new -keyout
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2/conf/privkey.pem" -passout
>   pass:**** -subj "/O=Bitnami/OU=Certificate generated at installation
>   time/CN=www.example.com" -out
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2/conf/server.csr": child killed:
>   unknown signal Installing Apache as a Windows service with name
>   wampstackApache Executing
>   D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2\bin\httpd.exe -k install -n
>   "wampstackApache" -f
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1\apache2\conf\httpd.conf"
>
> Script stderr:  child killed: unknown signal
>
> Error running D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/PEAR/.registry" "@@BITROCK_PHP_ROOT@@"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php": child killed: unknown signal
>   Executing D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/PEAR/.registry"
>   "@@BITROCK_APACHE_ROOTDIR@@" "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2"
>   Script exit code: unknown signal
>
> Script output:
>
> Script stderr:  child killed: unknown signal
>
> Error running D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php.exe -q
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/bin/fixreg.php"
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/PEAR/.registry"
>   "@@BITROCK_APACHE_ROOTDIR@@" "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1/apache2":
>   child killed: unknown signal Executing
>   D:/Apps/wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/pear config-create -w
>   "D:\Apps\wampstack-7.1.18-1\php" pear.ini Script exit code: 0

Anybody can help?

Thanks

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Could you please share with us more information about the installation (the version of the operating system, the memory it has, if you have antivirus enabled, ...). Instead of closing the installer when it reports the error, could you please open a command prompt and run the following command? `D:/Apps/wampstack-7.1.18-1/php/php -v`. Let us know if that returns any error message

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today. If you try to run `php.exe` binary from the bitnami folder, it should fail with the error `missing api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0-dll`. I solved the problem by downloading the update available at https://support.microsoft.com/pt-br/help/2999226/update-for-universal-c-runtime-in-windows.